# Magento2 - Secure your store from CSRF

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, security, csrf

Can anyone let me know how can I Secure store from CSRF. I am facing vulnerability issue like - Form Can Be Manipulated with Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Is this issue solved in Magento 2.4.4 version?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Tried one solution: Store admin can set Add Secret Key to URLs to yes from Stores>Configuration>Advanced>Admin>Security. This was enabled by default still in security test, this vulnerability is found.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Google recaptcha on all forms and and add form validation code level and set characters length in form fields.